# PPTP VPN in Cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

I want to setup PPTP VPN on my GSP Instance but I cant connect to it cause GCP doesn't support GRE Protocol. Is there any software to create VPN server so that I can set those credentials into my router's setting.
What if I create VPN in GCP instead of Windows Instance. Will it get connected?
Does AWS support GRE?

Answer (score 2):

Is there really need for PPTP? It might be [time to move on](https://www.howtogeek.com/211329/which-is-the-best-vpn-protocol-pptp-vs.-openvpn-vs.-l2tpipsec-vs.-sstp/).

- Google has IPsec based [Google Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/overview).
- AWS has documentation for [many solutions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpn-connections.html).
- And you could always install [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net).

Comment: But my allows only PPTP. I need this VPN for Privacy.

Comment: PPTP is old and vulnerable i.e. not good for privacy.